# Probability of $\{X_1 < X_2 < \cdots < X_n\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb N^*}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random continuous variables having a density $f$. Since $X_i$'s are continous we have 
$$  \mathbb P(X_i=X_j) = 0 $$. and since $X_i$'s are identically distributed we can show that $ \mathbb P(X_i<X_j)=\mathbb  P(X_i>X_j)$. In fact, the density of $-X_j$ is $\tilde f: x \to f(-x)$, the density of $X_i-X_j$ is therefore $f \ast \tilde f$. $X_i-X_j$ and $X_j-X_i$ have the same law so $ \mathbb P(X_i<X_j)=\mathbb  P(X_i>X_j)$ and  $ \mathbb P(X_i<X_j) = \frac{1}{2}$.

My problem is how to show that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and each permutation $\sigma $ of $\{1,...,n\}$ we have

$$
\mathbb P (X_{\sigma(1)} < \cdots <X_{\sigma(n)}) = \frac{1}{n!}
$$

Comment: Why can't you just use the same *$X_i$s being independently and identically distributed* argument you used for  $\mathbb P(X_i<X_j)=\mathbb  P(X_i>X_j)$ to say that each permutation has the same probability and there are $n!$ permutations?

Comment: The problem I encountred here is that if I write $$ \mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3) = \mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2 \ and \ X_2<X_3)  $$ I can't use indepence here because I have $X_2$ in both sides.

Comment: The i.i.d.-ness tells that $(X_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, X_{\sigma(n)})$ has the same joint distribution as $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$. which is all that you need to get $$\mathbb{P}(X_{\sigma(1)}<\cdots<X_{\sigma(n)}) = \mathbb{P}(X_1<\cdots<X_n).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes I see that, but i need a regorous proof such the one we have of the case $n=2$.

Comment: You can easily check that the joint PDF of $(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(n)})$ and $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ are the same, and that the probability can be computed by integrating the indicator function w.r.t. the joint PDF $$ \mathbb{P}(X_1<\cdots<X_n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbf{1}(x_1<\cdots<x_n) f_{X_1,\cdots,X_n}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n. $$ Since the right-hand side coincides for both the $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ and its permutations, the probability must be the same.

Comment: Now it's clear, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $S_n$ the permutation group of $\{1, \dots, n\}.$
Since $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d., the distrubtion of the random vector $(X_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, X_{\sigma(n)})$ does not depend on the permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, neither does the probability of $\mathbb(X_{\sigma(1)} < \dots < X_{\sigma(n)})$. One has for any fixed $\sigma \in S_n$,
\begin{align*}
1 &= \sum_{\tau \in S_n} \mathbb{P}(X_{\tau(1)} < \dots < X_{\tau(n)})  \\
&\quad+\mathbb{P}(\left\{\exists 1 \leq i < j \leq n \text{ s.t. } X_i = X_j\right\}),\\ 
&= n! \mathbb{P}(X_{\sigma(1)} < \dots < X_{\sigma(n)}),
\end{align*}
which concludes that 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{\sigma(1)} < \dots < X_{\sigma(n)}) = \frac{1}{n!}.$$